# Dynamics Columns Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a report that columns have some Day of the week.

[image]

Every week I have a new report and these weeks are updated. Com generates an error and I have to edit the DAX. I was wondering if there is any way that I can work in the form of an index and not by the name of the column

Example:

Firts week i have headers "Employee","05/15/2020", "05/23/2020..."
Another week (new report) my headers change by "Employee","07/11/2020", "07/18/2020..."

When changed the week my headers changed and the update crash because my headers changed.

My idea question is:

If there is any way to reference a column (via query) without informing the column name, but some "index" so you don't have to maintain the code.

Comment: Hi There, Question is not very clear, Can you please elaborate a bit and show us what you are looking out for?

Comment: You can use unpivoting the data in the query editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to have a more dynamic f.e. "Change Type"-Step in you query, you can get the columnnames from a previous step.

You have to change the automatic generated step from (example):

```
ChangeType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"County", type text}, {"City", type text}}),
```

To:

```
ChangeType = Table.TransformColumnTypes( Source, 
                                         List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), 
                                                        each {_ , type text}
                                                       )
                                        ),
```

Table.Columnnames catches the columnnames from an other Table as List
List.Transform combines the two Lists (Table.Columnnames and {, type text}

best regards chris